# How To Display Multiple Value From Table Mysql To Textarea Field With Looping Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, textarea

I have a 2 value in my DB

```
+--------------+------------------+-----------+
|    id_des    |     deskripsi    |   id_srt  |
+--------------+------------------+-----------+
|      1       |       Test 4     |     4     |
|      2       |       Test 2     |     4     |
+--------------+------------------+-----------+
```

I want to display the `deskripsi` value where `id_srt = '4'` to my textarea field (sample)

But they are not visible when I run the script:

[image]

As you can see, the textarea field isn't visible.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$id = isset ($_POST['id_srt']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM deskripsisrt WHERE id_des = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?> 
    </br>
    <a href="#" style=\"color:#EC090D; cursor:pointer; text-align: Right;\" onclick="hapusElemen(\'#srow' + desc + '\'); return false;">hapus</a>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea rows="6" cols="100" type="text" class="desce form-control" name="deskripsi[]" id="deskripsi" placeholder="deskripsi" size="100"><?php echo $row ['deskripsi']; ?>
        </textarea>
    </br>
    </div>
    <?php
}?>
```

So my question how to display a multiple value on `textarea`?

Comment: Side note, you should use prepared statements, rather than taking the id directly from the request and sticking it in your sql.  Doing so opens your sql up to sql injection attacks.

Comment: i am new on programing, i dont know how to make it safe from sql injection?

Answer (score 0):

change your sql query to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM deskripsisrt WHERE id_srt = '$id'";
```

Comment: sory my bad :D, but i found 1 solution about value from table to textarea ,.. but the while position like this  <pre><code> <textarea rows="6" cols="100" type="text" class="desce form-control" name="deskripsi[]" id="deskripsi" placeholder="deskripsi" size="100">
<?php
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
 echo $row ['deskripsi']; 
 ?>
</textarea></code></pre>   the while exist on text area tag ,.. yeah thats work for me but just 1 value showing,.. i need 2 value to show on deskripsi ,.. i think i need loop but i new on programing i dont know how make loop can you give me sample ?

Answer (score 0):

So after editing my code i found a problem in here

`$id = isset ($_POST['id_srt']);`

The $id never get valu from input field,.. 
So anybody can help me to fix my code to get value $id ?